# How to combine JSF and Wicket components on same page

Tags: java, jsf, wicket

Is there way I can combine a JSF component and a Wicket component in the same web page? 
 I have a menu bar component created in Wicket and a form component is created in JSF.
 I have to combine these two components in one page, is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible.

I'd need to know a bit more about your situation to give much real advice, but [this wiki entry](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/including-jsp-files-in-html-templates.html) indicates one possible tactic.

Cobbling things together this way is not likely to be the best approach though.  If you can't easily make a wicket component that does the same thing as your jsf component (or vice versa), you've probably got too much logic in your presentation code.

Move as much of the work as you can into plain old java classes, and see if you can just use one framework.

Comment: Thanks @Don. This wiki link is interesting. I am creating an application where there is in admin page. For which functionality is already defined in another application with JSF component. For ex:adding user, role etc... For this reason I want to use JSF component in Wicket page

Comment: this obviously works for JSPs, but I'm not that sure about JSF. After all, JSF components also have state.

Comment: @seanizer Indeed, I don't know all the details of combining JSF and Wicket, and would prefer to just stick with Wicket.

Comment: Thank you @don and @seanizer. Due to time constraints we are using existing JSF components wherever possible. We decided to use iframes to integrate JSF components in wicket pages.

Answer (score -2):

Few information for 2017 year

Old integration attempts evolve forward.

Now project has name `wicketstuff-jee-web` (previously `wicket.jsp`)

https://github.com/klopfdreh/wicketstuff-jee-web

Promises integration of Wicket components and JSF components.
Is far more dynamic than old JSP integration, works at many stages of request.
Works in both directions, from Wicket context to embedded JSF components, and vice versa

Please read few words tutorial

Comment: For me it is hard to follow, hard to see the advantages and honestly, combining to 'competing'  frameworks in one webapp  is asking for problems

Comment: agree, not is easy. For example both have multi stage rhythm of live (states during request). But when we have part in A and want to build/test/integrate in B. Connecting different technologies is not normal in development, but good to have such tools

Comment: I dont undestarnd downvotes.My role is not promote integration - is is direct answer to question "Is there way,,,combine...in the same page"

Comment: Suppose the externak link is not working anymore. How useful is the answer then? Totally not. So it is not a good answer (link only answer)